# i can't handle a tag <image> in svg code

Tags: html, svg

i generated a svg code for a map in illustrator to put in my website but i had this code which has a tag called `<image>` which i can not handle, can't give it css properties nor just put a foreground text on it, my objective is to have that image or the g or the link changes foreground color as i hover over it, but i can't find any thing about that tag, there is only articles about path or circle or line for svg tags but not `<image>`
here's my code :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1434 1454.3" enable-background="new 0 0 1434 1454.3" xml:space="preserve">
<switch>
        <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
                <i:pgfRef  xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
                    </i:pgfRef>
            </foreignObject>
            <g i:extraneous="self">
        <a xlink:href="../Reservation/Second Level/index.php">
                        <g id="Inezgane_Ait_Melloul.svg_xA0_Image_1_">
                                <image overflow="visible" width="37" height="19" id="Inezgane_Ait_Melloul.svg_xA0_Image" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACUAAAAUCAYAAAAKuPQLAAAACXBIWXMAAA7DAAAOwwHHb6hkAAAA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" transform="matrix(0.75 0 0 0.75 728.25 568.5)">
                                    </image>
                            </g>
                    </a>
    </g>
    </switch>
```

it's not the full code because the full one is like thousand lines, the map has a lot of zones to cover.
but i'm kind of not familiar with svg at all, so maybe i'm doing something wrong in the concept of interactive map design

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't handle it"?  `<image>` is a standard SVG tag.  If you want to learn about `<image>`, the ultimate source is the SVG specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement

Comment: `<image>` provides a way to include other image files in your SVG. In most cases (and indeed in your sample) you are including a bitmap image - actually a PNG.  You can't style a PNG with CSS in SVG files. It's the same as HTML, you can't restyle PNG images in HTML either.

Comment: i meant i can't find a way to even trigger a small floating box with a name whenever i hover on that <image>, as you know what my purpose is, what is the solution for me to show a sign that the mouse is in top of the <image> with the name ****

Comment: You should mostly be able to do the same as if you were working with an HTML `<img>`.  You will likely need to use JS.  Also bear in mind that how you include the image matters.  For example, you won't be able to get hover events on your `<image>` if the SVG is included in your page using an `<img>` tag (eg. `<img src="my.svg">`).